# Maximum number of batched UPDATE statements in one query

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Knowing that one can batch together multiple UPDATE queries into a single query by appending a semi-colon to them, is there a maximum number of UPDATE statements allowed in one query?

Does it depend on the length of each single UPDATE query?

I'm trying to reduce the number of calls from a client to a server and am considering batching the queries together when the number of such queries exceeds a certain maximum.

Ex/

```
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = 'helloA', col3 = '2023-10-13 12:00:00' WHERE idCol = 5;
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = 'helloB', col3 = '2023-10-13 12:00:00' WHERE idCol = 6;
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = 'helloC', col3 = '2023-10-13 12:00:00' WHERE idCol = 7;
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = 'helloD', col3 = '2023-10-13 12:00:00' WHERE idCol = 8
```

Comment: *" is there a maximum number of UPDATE statements allowed in one query?"* A query can only contain *one* `UPDATE` as a query is a single statement. A *batch* (like you demonstrate above), however, can contain as many `UPDATE`s as you want, Though you would likely find that converting the above into a *single* `UPDATE` statement would be more performant, or you should wrap the above into a transaction. Unless these `UPDATE` statements are actually updated millions of rows each? But then I would suggest that having a column called `idCol` that isn't unique is a poor name choice.

Comment: The total length of the query can affect its performance. If you have a very long query with a large number of UPDATE statements, it may become less efficient to process and transmit over the network.

Comment: it's better to create a table value parameter and put all you update data there, and then do it in one join.

Comment: There is a maximum batch size but it's not based on the number of statements in a batch. There is a limit of 65,536 network packets per batch so for the default network packet size of 4 KiB that comes out to 256 MiB. If we're using UTF-16 encoding and only BMP characters then that's 134,217,728 characters - including line breaks and other whitespace characters. But do you really want to make batches that big? Not only do you have to transfer all that data across the network but SQL Server has to fit it all in memory to parse, compile and execute it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and no, I'm not looking to make it such large batches. My use-case was how we are sending each query across to the server as a grpc call and instead of making 100 such calls one-by-one, just batch them into one query and thus one grpc call to the server. 
Furthermore, I was more interested in the hard limit of the max number of UPDATE calls in one query and AlwaysLearning answered this for me. I was unable to locate the infomation myself online.